# Copy database with smo raise error: "user already exists"

Tags: c#, smo

I try to copy a database using smo, but I get the error:

> "User, group, or role '%' already exists in the current database"

My code:

```
var conn = GetServerConnection();
var server = new Server(conn);

var sourceDb = server.Databases[sourceDatabase.Name];

var destinationDbName = GetNameForDatabase(dbName);

var destinationDb = new Database(server, destinationDbName);
destinationDb.Create();

var transfer = new Transfer(sourceDb) {
   DestinationDatabase = destinationDbName,
   DestinationServer = server.Name,
   DestinationLoginSecure = true,
   CopySchema = true,
   CopyAllTables = true,
   CopyData = true,
   CopyAllUsers = false,
};

transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
transfer.TransferData();
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Try to turn off `CopyAllLogins` and/or `CopyAllRoles` properties.

Comment: I added the following code: `CopyAllRoles = false,
                CopyAllLogins = false` but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any mappings from the database server to the source database? Try removing those before attempting the copy.

I was copying the database using the Copy Database wizard in order to create a test database on the same server, and got this error. The problem was that the source database had a user login mapped to that database. Somewhere in the mix of it all, the Copy Database wizard was trying to add a user to the destination database via a straight copy, but also add the same user through the mapping. The trick was to remove the mapping of the source database, then copy the database, then add the mapping back to the source (it was already added at the destination).